# What are the alternatives for "In the name of God"?

Tags: phrase-request

I did a little digging, [here](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/in_the_name_of_the_lord/synonyms).
What I found is not what I want.

I know in the western culture, this is not prevalent to start a speech or lecture by a sentence like "In the name of God", but since in my culture this is popular I'm looking for phrases like "In the name of God" (which in our culture means that I start my [speech]/job with the name of God or is a kind of respect to God)

Is there such phrases I can use instead of "in the name of God" in the given circumstance?
Something general. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the US, at least, starting a sentence with "In the name of God..." is generally reserved for an exclamation of some sort, usually with a negative emphasis.

For example someone might say in response to a horrific crime:

> In the name of God what drives people to do such things?

If you are wishing to give honor to God or to give a blessing to someone you might say something like:

> Praise God that you made it through that storm safely.

or

> May God bless you as during your travel.

Comment: So, "In the name of God" is somehow the equivalent of "OH My God"?

Comment: @user48 It can be. Same as 'In God's name' or 'Mother of God'. 'Jesus' gets used that way a lot too.

Comment: It's hard to explain how relaxed people are about it because I can't fully explain the cultural attitudes towards Christianity in the UK, the US, Australia etc.

Answer (score 0):

Om Swastiastu,بسم الله , bismillah, or what ever it is in your language,  is a set phrase that is use in a wide variety of situations thoughout the world, including at the start of a speech or lecture.

Western society is largely secular, so there is no equivalent, and there is no other set phrase that is used to start a lecture.

"in the name of God" is usually used blasphemously to indicate surprise and annoyance, so it's best avoided.

Comment: But how do you really start a speech if not with the name of God? I mean you directly start (e.g.) reading your lecture? You don't say anything before starting? Or you say for example "**Ladies and gentlemen welcom"**?

Comment: @user48 That is normal from what I've seen. A speaker will (1) welcome and/or thank his audience for attending, (2) optionally tell a short joke to attempt to relax the audience, (3) start with a short synopsis about what he is going to talk about, and then (4) get into the meat of whatever his subject is.

Comment: @user48 A very formal speech might begin with something like "Ladies and gentlemen, honored guests..." before going into the subject.  A very informal speech might begin, "Hey, guys!  What's up?  How's everybody doing?  I'm here to tell you about ____!"

Comment: Even in earlier centuries when it was taken for granted that everyone in Europe was a Christian, I've never heard of a formula of that kind being used to begin a speech. A sermon in church will often begin with something like "May I speak in the name of God...", but not an ordinary speech.

Comment: Ooh, something came to my mind, they translate "بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم" as "in the name of God, the compassionate, the merciful" is this translation in the English wrong? (I'm not asking about the meaning of it, I'm asking about the structure and the English points) I mean if I say this, will the native speaker understand or it seems weird to them?

Comment: @user48 The addition of "the compassionate, the merciful" changes a lot. That would sound like you're reading from a religious text. Whereas "in the name of God" on it's own is a common example of "using the Lord's name in vain."

Comment: There is one famous example where "in the name of God" was used quite seriously (by a believer who thought he was enacting God's will): Oliver Cromwell's speech dismissing the English Parliament in 1653 ( https://speakola.com/political/oliver-cromwell-speech-dismissing-rump-parliament-1653 ).  The same phrase "in the name of God, go!" was then used by Leo Amery, addressing the prime minister, in 1940 ( https://www.huffpost.com/entry/in-the-name-of-god-go_b_821008 ).  Whether or not Amery thought he was acting in God's name, he was expressing his righteous views.

Comment: I thought of something related: it is not actually part of the speech, but some organizations may begin a session with a prayer.  For example, every session of the Senate of the United States begins with [a prayer led by the Senate chaplain](https://chaplain.house.gov/archive/index.html).

Comment: @user48: ""in the name of God, the compassionate, the merciful" is an accurate and reasonably natural translation, though it has quite a literary feel. That's probably appropriate for a religious set phrase.